# Attendance Mark using JSON and PHP

Tags: php, android, json

I am making an app for attendance marking system.
So whenever a class will be selected all its students will be displayed and there will be a radio button for present and absent in front of each student and then again after marking the attendance for the class. The list again will be send back to php file to check who were present and not.

I want to ask how the name and radio buttons should be sent.
Should I send only the names and roll numbers using json.
Or also the radio buttons and how to mark the attendance.

If sending radio button using json is better then how can it be done.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, radio buttons are only for making one selection from a list. In your case I would recommend using checkboxes instead. Second, using PHP, you should use a loop, my preference is foreach loops, to create the list of students in the class. Third, the list should be in a html form for submitting back to a PHP file. You will have to come up with the rest as StackOverflow is here to help you if you are having problems with a code and you can't quite figure it out, not for figuring out how to write code in the first place.